# Magento seems to have upper limits for stores

Tags: stores, cli

I have forked another project to create a CLI build script for adding thousands of Magento stores to a single instance of Magento. Here is the build script: https://gist.github.com/jadissa/1812cdf8f14b29670ec9#file-index-php

Here's the wrapper for calling it which can receives a number parameter for how many stores to create: https://gist.github.com/jadissa/1812cdf8f14b29670ec9#file-benchtest-php

The script creates the store group and then creates three views (english, french and spanish) for the each group. I noticed that once I went past around 100 records, Magento no longer loads.

We have attempted to clear the cache: `rm -rf var/cache/*`
We've restarted Apache.
We have added 4 cores to this machine and have added 6.144 GB of RAM to this Ubuntu system we have on the cloud.

PHP dies with the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Element.php on line 417

We bumped the `max_execution` time up and set PHP's memory at 2GB. It can now load... 200 stores. We want at least 2k stores though.

What's slowing things down so badly?

Answer (score 2):

I can only speculate here, but I guess the config xml ends up being too big to handle.
The full config file is generated like this:

```
<config>
    <global><!-- not store dependent -->
        ...
    </global>
    <admin><!-- not store dependent -->
        ....
    </admin>
        ...a lot of other stuff in between that are not store dependent
    <default><!-- not store dependent -->
        ...
    </default>
    <websites>
        <websites1_code><!-- websites dependent -->
            ....
        </websites1_code>
        <websites2_code><!-- websites dependent -->
            ....
        </websites2_code>
        ....
        <websites_n_code><!-- websites dependent -->
            ....
        </websites_n_code>
    </websites>
    <stores>
        <store1_code><!-- store dependent -->
            ....
        </store1_code>
        <store2_code><!-- store dependent -->
            ....
        </store2_code>
        ....
        <store_n_code><!-- store dependent -->
            ....
        </store_n_code>
    </stores>
</config>
```

A lot of those values are duplicated for easier reading, but I guess this ends up too large to parse.

Comment: Yes,  SimpleXml is slow enough already, making it build a config tree for 200 stores is brutal. I fear, Magento is not suitable for this kind of setup.